# build troubles when adding tests to XCode 5 project

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, xcode5

I decided it was time to write some tests for my iPhone app.  Unfortunately, this hasn't gone well.  I created a new test class but get the error below.  It looks like it's pulling in OS X libraries to me but I have no idea why....

```
Ld /Users/philswenson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3rdRevolution-crkklmdwurdjtrbjvjedcqqeoyvk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/3rdRevolutionTests.octest/3rdRevolutionTests normal i386
cd /Users/philswenson/dev/3rdRev/3R_iOS
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 7.0
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/philswenson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3rdRevolution-crkklmdwurdjtrbjvjedcqqeoyvk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/philswenson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3rdRevolution-crkklmdwurdjtrbjvjedcqqeoyvk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/philswenson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3rdRevolution-crkklmdwurdjtrbjvjedcqqeoyvk/Build/Intermediates/3rdRevolution.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/3rdRevolutionTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/3rdRevolutionTests.LinkFileList -bundle_loader /Users/philswenson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3rdRevolution-crkklmdwurdjtrbjvjedcqqeoyvk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/3rdRevolution.app/3rdRevolution -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -framework SenTestingKit -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/philswenson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3rdRevolution-crkklmdwurdjtrbjvjedcqqeoyvk/Build/Intermediates/3rdRevolution.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/3rdRevolutionTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/3rdRevolutionTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/philswenson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3rdRevolution-crkklmdwurdjtrbjvjedcqqeoyvk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/3rdRevolutionTests.octest/3rdRevolutionTests

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XCTestCase", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_IsoDateTest in IsoDateTest.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_XCTestCase", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_IsoDateTest in IsoDateTest.o
  "__XCTFailureFormat", referenced from:
      -[IsoDateTest testExample] in IsoDateTest.o
  "__XCTFailureHandler", referenced from:
      -[IsoDateTest testExample] in IsoDateTest.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

here is a screenshot of my Framework Search Paths setting:  [image: http://cl.ly/T7gV]

any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From reading "I decided it was time to write some tests," I'm guessing it's been a while since you created the project. So maybe…

- You created the project using Xcode 4. The test target would use SenTestingKit.
- You added IsoDateTest.m using Xcode 5. The latest file template uses XCTest.

Check the list of libraries under the test target's build settings. Replace SenTestingKit.framework with XCTest.framework.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the backslashes in the target's framework settings as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22033984/35690) did the trick for me.