# How to solve Mach-O-Linker error in ios7 & Xcode 5.0.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I cannot compile my project for the  simulator .
 I get  Apple Mach-O-Linker error.I cant understand how to solve the issues.I am using xcode 5.0.1.
Please help me any body.
 Thanks in advance.

```
Ld /Users/murthych/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClassifiedDetails-elseirogpshyhmffphsiejgydphd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ClassifiedDetails.app/ClassifiedDetails normal i386
    cd /Users/murthych/Desktop/ClassifiedDetails
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 7.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/murthych/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClassifiedDetails-elseirogpshyhmffphsiejgydphd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/murthych/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClassifiedDetails-elseirogpshyhmffphsiejgydphd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/murthych/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClassifiedDetails-elseirogpshyhmffphsiejgydphd/Build/Intermediates/ClassifiedDetails.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ClassifiedDetails.build/Objects-normal/i386/ClassifiedDetails.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -framework XCTest -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/murthych/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClassifiedDetails-elseirogpshyhmffphsiejgydphd/Build/Intermediates/ClassifiedDetails.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ClassifiedDetails.build/Objects-normal/i386/ClassifiedDetails_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/murthych/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClassifiedDetails-elseirogpshyhmffphsiejgydphd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ClassifiedDetails.app/ClassifiedDetails
```

Mach-O-Linker error message

```
building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/‌​XCTest' for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) "
```

Comment: Can you compile without running the project?

Comment: Do you have any static library included supporting only iOS device? Could you also ensure to include all the required frameworks?

Comment: Any body help me please.I am struck this one............

Comment: I don't think you pasted the whole message. There should be lines at the end that say "Mach-O-Linker error: description of the error will be here".  Build again and post the actual linker errors so we can see what's failing.

Comment: i Got the Mach-O-Linker error message "building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`XCTest.framework` needs to be linked only to the unit test target in your project. It should not be added to the UI application target.

What I have found is when adding `XCTest.framework` Xcode adds extra `\` to `Framework Search Paths`

```
\"$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks\"
\"$(DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks\"
$(DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR)
```

[image]

This causes linker issue,

```
ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

To resolve this issue in XCode 5.1 goto the main ProjectWindow, Tab **Build Settings** -> Section **Search Path** -> **Framework Search Paths** and edit to remove `\` appearing the paths.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Arrrrg!  This has gotten me in the past.  I recently started working on an old project and it happened again!  I knew the fix was easy but just forgot what it was.  YOU ARE A GODSEND!!

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the test target and creating a new one and then copying the tests over can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use xcode 5.02 stable version and then hopefully these Mac-O Linker errors will be resolved.same problems I am facing too before installing xcode 5.02.

Comment: There are a hundred different reasons for a linker error that don't have to do with the version of XCode. While it certainly is possible that the version of xCode is the source of a linker error, There are tons of other plausible explanations that should be ruled out first. That said, Irfan is right, you should upgrade to 5.0.2 regardless.

Comment: This is incorrect. I faced this issue with latest Xcode 5.0.2 as well. Check my answer for solution.

Comment: @Amar there are not one reason which causes Mac-O Linker error, there are many other reasons too. In my case it resolved by updating xcode and in your case it resolved as you mentioned in your answer. And still I sure there will be many other reasons which causes Mac-O Linker error as ryan cumley mentioned above.

Comment: @Irfan `building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/‌​XCTest' for architecture i386` is one single reason. It does not help by upgrading to Xcode 5.0.2 as your answer suggests. I can still reproduce it.

Comment: @Amar Yes I am agreed with your answer may you figured out the exact problem of this specific Mac-O Linker error, but I am just taking the general example of Mac-O Liker error.