# How can i solve this Mach o linker error in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, linker, xcode5

I'm unable to compile my project for the simulator .
I get Apple Mach-O-Linker error.I'm unable to solve this issues.I am using xcode 5.
I get the same question here [How to solve Mach-O-Linker error in ios7 & Xcode 5.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032987/how-to-solve-mach-o-linker-error-in-ios7-xcode-5-0-1) with right answer,but in my case there is "\" in Framework Search Path.

```
         Ld /Users/mohit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Story-                    cfxrnsmqxnasuafarmhvchwphnxa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Story.app/Story normal i386
         cd "/Users/mohit/Desktop/ys_xcode/YS Code/Story 34"
      export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
      export      PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/     usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang - arch i386 -isysroot    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i        PhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/mohit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Story-  cfxrnsmqxnasuafarmhvchwphnxa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -   F/Users/mohit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Story-    cfxrnsmqxnasuafarmhvchwphnxa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -  F/Users/mohit/Documents/FacebookSDK -  F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Users/mohit/Desktop/ys_xcode/YS\ Code/Story\ 34 -filelist   /Users/mohit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Story-    cfxrnsmqxnasuafarmhvchwphnxa/Build/Intermediates/Story.build/Debug-  iphonesimulator/Story.build/Objects-normal/i386/YourStory.LinkFileList -Xlinker -  objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs   -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework XCTest -framework Social -framework CoreData -  framework GoogleOpenSource -framework CoreMotion -framework AssetsLibrary -framework    AddressBook -framework FacebookSDK -lxml2 -framework GooglePlus -Xlinker -dependency_info -  Xlinker /Users/mohit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Story-  cfxrnsmqxnasuafarmhvchwphnxa/Build/Intermediates/Story.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Story.build/Objects-normal/i386/Story_dependency_info.dat -o     /Users/mohit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Story-     cfxrnsmqxnasuafarmhvchwphnxa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Story.app/Story
```

Mach-O-Linker error message

```
      ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file   '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' for   architecture i386
      clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)]
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: `building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file   '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' for   architecture i386`
Isn't this it?

Comment: @ Schemetrical thanks,Building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' for architecture i386..yes this is.